# Images transition jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

My animation is working but not completely clean. As you can see,
It starts blocky and if the animation is done, It goes back to normal (to the image).
I want it to be not blocky, So my animation looks smooth.

better viewing in full screen mode

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>The jQuery Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#show").ready(function () {
                $(".target1").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
            });

            $("#show").ready(function () {
                $(".target2").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
            });

            $("#show").ready(function () {
                $(".target3").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<img src="https://image.ibb.co/eMn59m/Samir_Boven.png" id="blauw" class="target1"
     style="margin-top: 10px; width: 100%; height: 300px; display: none">
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/n4WAaR/Samir_Midden.png" id="geel" class="target2"
     style="margin-top: -70px; width: 100%; height: 300px; display: none">
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/hLZ7N6/Samir_Onder.png" id="blauw2" class="target3"
     style="margin-top: -40px; width: 100%; height: 300px; display: none">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what element has the id `show`

Comment: first image = target1, second = target2, third = target3.

Answer (score 1):

animating with slides its heavy for browser because of animation are rendered by changing numerical values and using cpu.

You can add a Jquery animate replacement with Transit library which adds the nice feature of using css for transition (GPU accelerated) so

```
function floatIn($element) {
  $element.css({ 'opacity': 0, 'margin-top': 200px });
  $element.animate({ 'opacity': 1, 'margin-top': 0 }, { duration: 500 });
}
```

Will run by far smoother than your method in this case.